# How to retrieve all settings with OrmLiteAppSettings in one call?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm using the TextFileSettings and OrmLiteAppSettings together via MultiAppSettings, but would prefer to pre-read all the database settings in one call versus on demand, is there a way to do that, so that everything is in memory?

Below is the relevant code:

```
        OracleDialect.Provider.NamingStrategy = new OrmLiteNamingStrategyBase();
        OracleDialect.Provider.StringSerializer = new JsonStringSerializer();

        var fileSettings = new TextFileSettings(ConfigUtils.GetAppSetting("PathToSecuredFile"));
        var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(fileSettings.GetString("LeadDbConfigKey"), OracleOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance);
        var dbSettings = new OrmLiteAppSettings(dbFactory);
        var multiSettings = new MultiAppSettings(fileSettings, dbSettings);
        container.Register<IAppSettings>(c => multiSettings);
```

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preload all db App Settings you can just read the entire `ConfigSetting` db table into a .NET `Dictionary` and wrap it in `DictionarySettings`, e.g:

```
using (db = dbFactory.Open())
{
    var allDbSettings = db.Dictionary<string,string>(
        db.From<ConfigSetting>().Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Value}));

    var multiSettings = new MultiAppSettings(
        fileSettings, 
        new DictionarySettings(allDbSettings));
}
```